# Date formatter crashes romanian language in Xcode

Tags: swift

Below is the code to convert the string to date, which works perfectly for other languages but doesn't work when I change the iPad language to Romanian. Basically, it crashes when it finds it nil in the 5th line. But in English or any other language, this code perfectly converts to date.Any thought?

```
let dateOfProcedure = "03. Jun 2021 15:12:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat  = "dd. MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
let examDate = dateFormatter.date(from:dateOfProcedure)!
```

Comment: "which works perfectly for other languages " Which other languages? And let's think the reverse, what would be the output with your current code of `dateFormatter.string(from: Date())`? Does it look like `dateOfProcedure` Is there a 24h/12h format difference when you set Romanian hour?

Comment: 1I tested with English and Spanish and dutch which is working fine. 2. I checked iPad its 24hrs format @Larme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the locale for the formatter to one that matches the input. Assuming it is English you can use

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

Or use some other identifier where the language is English. Then if you want to convert it to another language you need a second formatter with the locale set to the language you want and use it to format a string from your Date object (`examDate`)

Below is a full example that parses the string and then format it into a Swedish date

```
let dateOfProcedure = "03. Jun 2021 15:12:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat  = "dd. MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
if let examDate = dateFormatter.date(from:dateOfProcedure) {
    let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
    outputFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "sv_SE")
    outputFormatter.dateStyle = .full
    
    print(outputFormatter.string(from: examDate))
} else {
    //Handle formatting error
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work with both .autoupdatingCurrent and .current.

Comment: @Dipesh sorry, I misread the question. Please see the updated answer.